# The size of the video in iTunes is very small and won't change sizes

Tags: itunes, video

The size of the video window in iTunes is very small. When I move the mouse over it the mouse cursor disappears. There are no buttons on the window and no context menu appears when right clicking.

I've tried going to Window > Zoom and nothing changes. I've tried going to View > Exit Full Screen and nothing changes. I've gone to View > Video Playback and tried to select "in iTunes window" and "in separate window" but neither change anything. There is another option in View > Video, "Full Screen" but that is disabled.

Obviously, I've restarted iTunes.

How do I get videos to playback normally?

I'm using iTunes 12.3.0.44 and OSX 10.10.5.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the operating system fixed it. :P